How to proof a line of stationary points is globally attracting?
I have an SIS-model $(I_1,Q_1,I_2,Q_2)$ with two viruses and dormancy (quiescence) compartments: Both strains have infection rate $\beta$ and recovery rate $\gamma$. The infection periods are interrupted by excursions to the $Q$ compartments, where infected neither add to infection pressure nor recover. In the rescaled variables $x=I_1/N$, $u=Q_1/N$, $y=I_2/N$ the system reads
\begin{equation}\label{eq: deterministic SIIQQS rescaled}
       \begin{aligned}
        x' &= x \left( \beta (1-x-u-y-v) - \gamma - \omega_1 \right) + c_1 u\\
 u' &= \omega_1 x - c_1 u\\
        y' &= y \left( \beta (1-x-u-y-v) - \gamma - \omega_2 \right) + c_2 v\\
        v' &= \omega_2 y - c_2 v.
    \end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
I want to prove that this model settles on the line of stationary points given by
\begin{align}
    CL = \biggl\{ (x,u,y,v) = \left( x^{\ast}, \vartheta_1 x^{\ast}, \frac{r-(1+\vartheta_1)x^{\ast}}{1+\vartheta_2},  \vartheta_2 \frac{r-(1+\vartheta_1)x^{\ast}}{1+\vartheta_2} \right) : x^{\ast}\in \left[ 0, \frac{r}{1+\vartheta_1 } \right] \biggr\},
\end{align}
where $\vartheta_i=\frac{w_i}{c_i}$. In https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29959946/ proposition A.2 this is argued for by looking at the 2-dim system $P=x+y$ and $S=u+v$ and then stating that "the divergence of this system is negative, and thus the combination of the theorems of Bendixon–Dulac and Pointcaré – Bendixon
implies that trajectories $(P, S)$ tend to stationary points." They however considered only weak selection so they had $\omega_1=\omega_2$ and $c_1 = c_2$ in the deterministic limit; the result however should remain true for my case as well. But I can't go to $(P,S)$ directly. Does someone have an idea how this could be saved?
